# How to create/access action in Yii2?

Tags: php, view, controller, yii2, http-status-code-404

I want to render a view file with the name `ChildPage.php` at the specific url `... /index.php?r=site%2FChildPage`.

I wrote a small view and added in my `SiteController` Class the method:

```
public function actionChildPage()
    {
        return $this->render('ChildPage');
    }
```

Have I forgotten anything? All my other pages are working but at this Page I get the error:

```
Not Found (#404)
Page not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about [creating actions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#creating-actions) :

> By default, action IDs should contain these characters only: English letters in lower case, digits, underscores, and hyphens. (You can use hyphens to separate words.) For example, view, update2, and comment-post are all valid action IDs, while view? and Update are not.
>
> The names of the action methods are derived from action IDs according to the following procedure:
>
> - Turn the first letter in each word of the action ID into upper case.
> - Remove hyphens.
> - Prepend the prefix action.

You should simply use the following route : **`site/child-page`**